# Does a 3rd-party keyboard with Allow-Full-Access ALWAYS have access to text?

Tags: ios, keyboard, permission, sandbox, 3rd-party

As I understand from other posts, a keyboard can only:

- access full text with Allow-Full-Access enabled
- never access text inside sensitive (e.g. password) fields

But how does inactivity/background effect this?

For example, can a 3rd-party keyboard (with Allow-Full-Access enabled) access text input when it is NOT active (i.e. the default system keyboard is currently used for typing)?